# What does --no-source-include do in NVRTC?

Tags: c++, cuda, jit, compiler-options, nvrtc

NVIDIA's run-time CUDA compilation library, NVRTC, supports the compilation flag `--no-source-include`.  The documentation [describes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html#group__options) this flag as follows:

> The preprocessor by default adds the directory of each input sources to the include path. This option disables this feature and only considers the path specified explicitly.

I don't quite understand how this is meaningful for NVRTC, as opposed to a regular compiler: We feed NVRTC a single input source, as a null-terminated string; we do not provide it with the path of a source file to read. So what exactly does this flag do?

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html#include-syntax

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I'm not following. That's how `""` vs `<>` include directives work in C and C++. Are you saying that, with `--no-source-include`, they have the same meaning?